# R: XML xmlGetAttr() to select only part of an attribute

Tags: xml, r

I am working with an XML file. Here is part of it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

  <!DOCTYPE ggobidata SYSTEM "ggobi.dtd">

    -<ggobidata count="1">


      -<data name="data1">

        <description> This is XML created by GGobi </description>


          -<variables count="10">


            **-<categoricalvariable name="region" nickname="re">**


            -<levels count="3">

              <level value="1">South</level>

              <level value="2">Sardinia</level>

              <level value="3">North</level>

             </levels>

           </categoricalvariable>


         **-<categoricalvariable name="area" nickname="ar">**
```

I'm sorry if the formatting is off! I have bolded the 2 lines of code I am working on right now. Here is my problem, I want to return the "categoricalvariable name." I keep getting the "nickname" returned as well, but I do not want it. Here is my current code:

```
cvPath <- "//ggobidata/data/variables/categoricalvariable"
cvList <- xpathApply(myDoc, cvPath, xmlAttrs)
cvNames <- as.vector(unlist(cvList))
cvNames
```

And here is what it returns:

```
"region" "re"     "area"   "ar"
```

I am now trying to use the "xmlGetAttr()" function to select only the name and not the nickname, but I have not been successful. I keep getting "null." Does anyone know how I can obtain:

```
"region" "area"
```

as my output? Thank you so much for your help everyone, I really appreciate it!

Comment: What's the code you are using for `xmlGetAttr()`?  Try `xmlGetAttr(x, "nickname")` where `x` is the document

Comment: Try `unname(sapply(xpathApply(myDoc, cvPath, xmlAttrs), "[", "name"))`.

Comment: @lukeA your code worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: `xpathSApply(myDoc, cvPath, xmlGetAttr, "name")` should work too

Comment: @chrisS. your code works as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
cvList <- xpathApply(myDoc, cvPath, xmlGetAttr, "name")
```